# List all constraints in an Oracle schema

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I have got a block of code to list the constraints I have in a set of tables but it gives this error:

```
ORA-00904: "TOTAL_CUSTOMER_COUNTRY": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 1
```

The error is the same every time I remove a table from the statement. I have tried encasing the tables in ' ' marks but then the output is blank.

```
SELECT a.owner, a.table_name, constraint_type, a.constraint_name, 
column_name, search_condition, r_constraint_name 
FROM user_constraints A, user_cons_columns B 
WHERE A.constraint_name  = B.constraint_name 
AND A.table_name IN (bank_account, basket, country, credit_card,
customer, item, orders, paypal, seller, total_balance, 
total_customer_country) 
ORDER BY A.table_name, constraint_type;
```

Here is the whole statement I am using, I'm unsure where the error is coming from. Any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are querying the data dictionary views.  `TOTAL_CUSTOMER_COUNTRY` is not an attribute of USER_CONSTRAINTS or USER_CONS_COLUMNS.  It is a literal value - a table name - so you need to quote it.

> "I have tried encasing the tables in ' ' marks but then the output is blank."

Oracle stores object names in upper-case.  So you need to change the case as well.

This version of your query should select details for the tables you want.

```
SELECT a.owner, a.table_name, constraint_type, a.constraint_name, 
column_name, search_condition, r_constraint_name 
FROM user_constraints A, 
     user_cons_columns B 
WHERE A.constraint_name  = B.constraint_name 
AND A.table_name IN ('BANK_ACCOUNT', 'BASKET', 'COUNTRY', 'CREDIT_CARD',
'CUSTOMER', 'ITEM', 'ORDERS', 'PAYPAL', 'SELLER', 'TOTAL_BALANCE', 
'TOTAL_CUSTOMER_COUNTRY') 
ORDER BY A.table_name, constraint_type;
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise it would be case sensitive. Most of the statements I have used to far haven't given me that issue

Comment: When you create an object like this:  create table mytable -- it is created with an upper case name. That means its name is stored in the data dictionary in upper case.  When you simply reference it -- select * from mytable -- the parser makes that translation for you. But if you querying the data dictionary ABOUT that object, then you are simply selecting data from a table so you need to be aware of the case of that data.  If you create an object with double qutoes -- create "MyTable", then you force oracle to store the name in that mixed case and you'll always have to deal with it that way.